# Modify the output of alert()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

For some specific purpose I'm trying to change the way Chrome outputs objects and arrays via `alert()`.

Something like:

```js
let myObject = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};
alert(myObject);
```

prints **[object Object]**.

After some digging I found that I can modify this by adding the property `Symbol.toStringTag` on the `Object.prototype` using a custom getter function:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, Symbol.toStringTag, {
  "configurable": true,
  "enumerable": true,
  get: function() {
    return "MyReplacement";
  }
});

let myObject = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

alert(myObject);
```

This works and prints **[object MyReplacement]** just fine - though I'm still wondering where the brackets and the initial `object` come from.

Well, if I try to do the same on the `Array.prototype`, it simply prints the contents of the array - **1, 2, 3** - instead.

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, Symbol.toStringTag, {
  "configurable": true,
  "enumerable": true,
  get: function() {
    return "MyReplacement";
  }
});

let myArray = [1, 2, 3];

alert(myArray);
```

So obviously this is not the right thing to change for handling an array. What is it?

Comment: To be clear, this is a contrived example demonstrating the gist of an unspecified something else you want to do, correct? In other words, you're not asking "how can I print an object with `alert`", but more like "how do I monkey patch `alert`"?

Comment: I'd rather say I need to monkey patch the array methods utilized/called by `alert()`, to let `alert()` output whatever I want. ;)

Comment: It's just calling `toString()`. Patch that. But it won't just affect `alert()`, it will affect everything else that converts objects to strings.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Why not just write your own `myalert()` function that formats the objects the way you want? Or monkey-path `window.alert()` instead of the low-level Object methods.

Comment: `Array` has its own `toString()` method that overrides `Object.toString()`. It's roughly `Array.prototype.toString = function() { return this.join(','); }`

Comment: Well this is just an extremely simplified example. In my real use-case I also modify the output of `console.log()` but it was not possible to showcase this here so I just mentioned `alert()`. Patching `.toString` works for `alert()` but not for `console.log()`.

Comment: `console.log()` is much more complicated, because it doesn't just print the string, it creates live data that's linked to the original object. Notice the disclosure triangles in the output.

Comment: Exactly Barmar! That's why I need to do some deeper changes like modifying Symbol.toStringTag of the Object.prototype - which does not work with Array.prototype.